# Django - while creating object from request.POST from modelformset_factory takes lot of time and sometimes crashes server

Tags: python, django, django-forms

I am using modelformset_factory and in my view function I am using form_with_post = FormSet(request.POST)

But when form has errors i.e when I don't update required fields it takes lot of time to create forset object from request.POST approx 2-3 mins

However it does not throw any exception or errors but in djano-server's log sometimes I observe following error

> "nhandled exception in thread started by <bound method Command.inner_run of"

Am I doing any mistake or wrong thing?

My Model looks as follows:

```
class Un_Verified_bn_in(models.Model):
   id = models.IntegerField(primary_key=True)
   phrase =  models.CharField(max_length=30)
   author =  models.CharField(max_length=30,null=True)
   time = models.DateField(null=True)
   alternate_phrase = models.CharField(max_length=30,null=True)
   verified_by_usr =  models.BooleanField(max_length=30)
   verified_by_admin =  models.BooleanField(max_length=30)
   discard_word =  models.BooleanField(max_length=30)
```

My modelform looks as follows:

```
class Un_Verified_bn_in_form(ModelForm):

def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
    super(Un_Verified_bn_in_form, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
    instance = getattr(self, 'instance', None)
    if instance and instance.pk:
        self.fields['phrase'].widget.attrs['readonly'] = True
        self.fields['id'].widget.attrs['readonly'] = True

class Meta:
    model = Un_Verified_bn_in
    fields = ('id','phrase','alternate_phrase','discard_word')
    exclude = ('time','verified_by_usr','verified_by_admin','author')
```

My views.py is as follows:

```
def user_page(request,lang="bn",locale="bn_in"):

    FormSet =     modelformset_factory(Un_Verified_bn_in,form=Un_Verified_bn_in_form,extra=0)            
    query = Un_Verified_bn_in.objects.all().filter(verified_by_usr=False).filter(verified_by_admin=False)
    paginator = Paginator(query, 10)
    page = request.GET.get('page')
    usr_name = request.user
try:
    objects = paginator.page(page)
except PageNotAnInteger:
    objects = paginator.page(1)
except EmptyPage:
    objects = paginator.page(paginator.num_pages)

if request.method == 'POST':
    form_with_post = FormSet(request.POST)
    if form_with_post.is_valid():
        print "form is valid"
        instances = form_with_post.save(commit=False)
        for instance in instances:
            obj = Un_Verified_bn_in.objects.get(pk=instance.id)
            obj.author = request.user_name
            obj.verified_by_usr = True
            instance.save()
            obj.save()
     context = {'objects':objects,'formset': form_with_post}
     return render_to_response('unverified.html', context,
                              context_instance=RequestContext(request))
 else:
       page_query = query.filter(id__in=[object.id for object in objects])
       formset = FormSet(queryset=page_query)        
       context = {'objects': objects, 'formset': formset}
       return render_to_response('unverified.html', context,
                              context_instance=RequestContext(request))
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well you are looping through potentially very long list of objects, calling them up from base again and then saving them (twice if i read it correctly) - that is alot of queries.

What you could do is:

1) Pass the value of author to formset, add author as field to form, set it in form **init** method

2) add verified_to_usr to form as hidden field. Set it to True in form **init** method

3) just save the formset.

In response to comment - https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/forms/modelforms/#model-formsets. THe place where it says that if you do not pass queryset as parameter to formset, then it will use relevantmodel.objects.all() as default queryset. ([link](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/forms/modelforms/#changing-the-queryset)). I think you missed that before. I said you are looping through very long list there - i thought it was intentional, that you had not passed another queryset as value to formset. Thats where the problems come from was my guess.

alan

Comment: I think problem is in form_with_post = FormSet(request.POST) this line because excution blocks at this point. May be something is wrong in read only attributes

Comment: Changed my asnwer in response to your comment.

Comment: i have added this line form_with_post = FormSet(request.POST,queryset=Un_Verified_bn_in.objects.none()) Now i am getting exception [error] IndexError: list index out of range.I am little confused with this behaviour.

Comment: ohh got it form_with_post = FormSet(request.POST,queryset=page_query) solved the problem! thanks!

Comment: Good job. Still - i suggest you implement my ideas to further limit the queries you run in that view.